# Changing classes' canonical names in package

Tags: java, android, package, rome

A bit of background (not directly relevant as my question is quite general): I want to use Android ROME Feed Reader library to parse RSS feed that has media content. But ROME doesn't support media out of the box, so I want to make use of a media plugin which comes as a separate JAR and builds upon the original library.

So I have two JARs (for which I have no source code), and my gradle dependencies look like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile files('libs/android-rome-feed-reader-1.0.0.jar')
  compile files('libs/mediarss-0.2.3.jar')
}
```

The problem is that the package names from the Android version of ROME are all prefixed with `com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.` with respect to the original library.

For instance, Android ROME lib contains the following interface:

```
package com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.module;
public interface Module { /* ... */ }
```

While all the classes in the media plugin refer to the original canonical names:

```
public interface MediaModule extends com.sun.syndication.feed.module.Module { /* ... */ }
```

Quite naturally, compilation fails:

```
Error:(69, 34) error: cannot access Module
class file for com.sun.syndication.feed.module.Module not found
```

Is there a workaround for this? Can I somehow statically change the canonical names for all classes in the library? Or is there some other solution?

Thanks!

Comment: is it REALLY just repackaged?

Comment: On the project page it just says "Android ROME Feed Reader is a repackaging of ROME so that it works on Android devices". I'm not sure what they mean by that and how repackaging alone would make any difference. I thought there might be more to that but again, I found no sources. If I don't get it to work, I guess I'll resort to original ROME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha, thats a silly issue. Seen stuff like this before. Your easiest bet is this: [Jar Jar Links](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/).

Simple:

- Make a rules.txt in the same directory as jarjar.jar with the following:
- `rule com.google.rome.** com.foo.bar.@1`
- cd to te directory of jarjar.jar
- run `java -jar jarjar.jar rules.txt ~/path_to/old_jar ~/path_to/new_jar`

Should repackage everything for ya to not be silly.

Comment: Yes, that's _exactly_ what I was looking for! Worked like a charm, thank you!

If anyone ever needs this, I used
`rule com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.** com.@1` (leaving out `com.` causes an NPE)